# Recreating a 'merge table' in Swift

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I am rebuilding a prototype that we built in FileMaker previously in SwiftUI. I have a table of diseases:

```
struct Diseases: Codable, Hashable {
  let diseaseID: Int
  let isPrimary: String
  let languageISO3: String
  
}
```

and a table of symptoms:

```
struct Symptom: Codable, Hashable {
  let symptomID: String
  let symptomName: String
}
```

that I load through a jSON file and fill into a

```
  @Published var symptoms = [Symptom]()
```

and

```
  @Published var diseases = [Disease]()
```

From, in this case, CoreData I am loading a table that contains a diseaseID and records with symptomID's. I want to create a list where after I select a certain symptom with symptomID, it gives me a list of all diseases (diseaseID is fine) that have that symptomID in their table. How do I do this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How are `Diseases` and `Symptom` related? I don't see an array of `symptomID` under `Diseases`...

Comment: I am a bit confused as to your initial population of the date. You say you load a `JSON` file into an `ObservableObject` class and 2 `@Published` variables, but you later say you are loading from CoreData. You really haven't included enough code here. That being said, why are you using the class with the `symptoms` and `diseases` when you could just use CoreData. You can define the relationships between the two, and the CoreData classes will trigger updates in your UI without using the `ObservableObject`

Comment: I suspect you have a many-to-many relationship, a disease can have many symptoms and a symptom could point to many diseases, and that is what you are referring to with ‘merge table’ but it is in no way clear what you are asking. The last part of the question points to Core Data but I don’t understand what entities you have an how they are related.

Comment: It is called a relationship https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html